# If statement with the Game.IsKeyDown not working as intended

Tags: c#, if-statement, keypress

EDIT: I fixed it using the code below.

I am trying to make a simple if statement that sees if the player is near fire. If he is near the fire and the key is not pressed he would receive damage as indicated. This works perfectly. However if the key is pressed the player will still be receiving damage.

The damage boolean is defined above the class as `static bool damage = false;`

```
            if (isPlaying)
            {
                player.Stop();
                Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof = false;

            }
            else
            {
                player.PlayLooping();
                Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof = true;


            }
```

What should I do in order to when the player is near the fire location AND the key is pressed to not take damage?

Comment: show us the code for Game.IsKeyDown(Settings.SCBA)

Comment: and whats this; `locationData.GoToPosition` and how does it relate to the 'fire' and why do you use distancesquared instead of distance?

Comment: The `locationData.GoToPosition` is the actual position of the fire. That works. I am sure about it as if i get near i get the damage. The code for the Settings.SCBA is a simple class that uses windows media player to play a sound effect. It activates like that                 `if (Game.IsKeyDown(Settings.SCBA))
                {
                    SCBA.PlaySound();
                }` It uses the default soundplayer

Comment: Sounds like `Game.IsKeyDown(Settings.SCBA)` is not returning `true`. To test, replace that with `if(true) { damage = false; } else { .... }` If that prevents damage, you'll have to figure out why `IsKeyDown` isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much here for us to go on, but I think that you're confusing your logic here.

The Key press ensures that `Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof = true` it should only be used to do that and probably outside of the code that you've presented to us so far.

Then your code would be:

```
if (Vector3.DistanceSquared(Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Position, locationData.GoToPosition) < 10f )
{
    if( Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof != true)
    {            
        Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Health -= 1;
    }
}
```

** edit **

Okay. Further to your comments.

I'm not sure whether or not `Game.IsKeyDown(...)` returns true if the key is pressed or not.

As its not really good practice to place function calls within logic statements, as they are difficult to debug try:

```
if (Vector3.DistanceSquared(Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Position, locationData.GoToPosition) < 10f )

    {
        bool damage != Game.IsKeyDown(Settings.SCBA);

        if( damage == true)

        {            

            Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Health -= 1;

        }

    }
```

If pressing or releasing the key has no effect then `Game.IsKeyDown` isn't doing what you expect it to.

Comment: I want when I press the key that this statement would be true `Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof != true` and this         `Game.LocalPlayer.Character.Health -= 1;` false. Like If you dont press the key the health of the player is decreasing. But If you press the key the health wont decrease

Comment: if I leave out the `Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof != true` then would it be easier? Like when I press the button player does not receive damage if dont press it player receives damage

Comment: I also added a boolean but still no luck and I completely removed the `Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsFireProof`